# No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present

Tags: asp.net-web-api, access-control

I have put the parameter in the web.config of the web.api that is being called. I even put it in the webapiconfig.cs to allow all sites hit the web.api. Even put it on the controller. And I still get this message? The calling website is sending json over to my web api. Why would I , could I be getting this error? What information can I give you guys to help me figure out this issue?

In reply to the solutions listed below: Here is the piece of my web.config....I put the wildcard of asterisk in it:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Within my webapiconfig.cs file I have the following as well:

```
{
    // enable CORS
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "*"));
}
```

And here is my controller. I know, overkill, but I am trying to figure out this issue:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class ExampleController : ApiController
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check your web.config file and search for system.webServer section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
            <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept" />             
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I did do this, with and without an asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for the general idea of what's going on, and http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api for how to solve it in ASP.net

Essentially, if your request is coming from one server to another on a different domain, the other server must say it's happy to accept requests from browsers on the first domain.

To fix it, tell ASP.net to return 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers that include the origin your request is coming from, either via web.config (as in the other answer), or by adding to your config and controller classes as below:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        // ...
    }
}

namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://myclientdomain.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks PimTerry and Thiago, but I did do all of those things. But it isn't happy to accept the request. See my edits on my initial question. Once again, thanks for your input. Any other ideas?